# Switching one icon button switches all icon buttons in my component

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, e-commerce

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce project using API made in laravel but the problem is that, I have made a wishlist button and when I click the wishlist button  on a single product, it will click all the wishlist button.

This is my **productdetails.html**:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center class="mynewr11">
 <ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
  <img class="myimg11" src="{{product.image}}" />
  <p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Price:</strong> ₹{{ product.product_actual_price * product?.count }}</p>
  <ion-col class="qty">
    <button (click)="decreaseProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      -
    </button>
    <button ion-button small clear color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      {{product?.count}}
    </button>
    <button (click)="incrementProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mynewbtn11">
      +
    </button>
</ion-col>
  <button class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
  <button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" *ngIf="!heart_clicked" (click)="addtoWishlist(true,product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" *ngIf="heart_clicked" (click)="addtoWishlist(false,product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon name="ios-heart"></ion-icon>
  </button>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

In this html, I am showing all products.

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from '../../providers/cart/cart';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetails',
  templateUrl: 'productdetails.html',
})
export class ProductdetailsPage {
  heart_clicked: boolean = false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController) 
  {}

  decreaseProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 1;
    }
    if (product.count > 1) {
      product.count--;
    }
  }

  incrementProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 1;
    }
    product.count++;
  }

  addtoWishlist(a,product){
    if(a==true){
      this.heart_clicked=true;
    }else
    {
        this.heart_clicked=false;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

In this picture, when I click on one wishlist button and it will check all wishlist button. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your Problem

All your wishlist buttons on the page are displayed depending on the same component variable `heart_clicked`.

```html
<button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" *ngIf="!heart_clicked" (click)="addtoWishlist(true,product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" *ngIf="heart_clicked" (click)="addtoWishlist(false,product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon name="ios-heart"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

When any wishlist button is clicked the function `addtoWishlist()` is called which sets the variable `heart_clicked` accordingly.

```ts
heart_clicked: boolean = false;

addtoWishlist(a,product){
    if(a==true){
      this.heart_clicked=true;
    }else
    {
      this.heart_clicked=false;
    }
  }
```

As all your wishlist html icons have `*ngIf="heart_clicked"` or `*ngIf="!heart_clicked"` specified they all depend on the same component wide variable.

#### My suggestion

You could add the `heart_clicked` variable to your `product` so that the wishlist button for every product has it's own variable `product.heart_clicked`.

I would then rename `product.heart_clicked` to `product.onWishlist` and set the icon to display according to this variable. You'll only need one button in your template then.

```html
<button ion-button icon-only class="wish-list-btn card" (click)="toggleOnWishlist(product)" color="light" class="mywisbtn11">
    <ion-icon [name]="product.onWishlist ? 'ios-heart' : 'heart-outline'"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

---

```ts
toggleOnWishlist(product){
  product.onWishlist = !product.onWishlist;
}
```

Comment: I have defined heart_clicked as false in the product.  in the function, I have to define like this  product.heart_clicked=true;.

Comment: @Raghav Are you asking me? In your question you are certainly not using product.heart_clicked. If your code is different from the one you posted in your question please add the correct code to your question.

Comment: Then what is your answer. can you please help me with your answer.

Comment: @Raghav I tried to explain my suggestion better. Please try the code I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but ios-heart : heart-outline is showing error. Error: Identifier 'ios' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member.

Comment: try to insert them as strings, i.e. `product.onWishlist ? 'ios-heart' : 'heart-outline'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186480/discussion-between-raghav-and-fridoo).